# Redux subscribed async State empty

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a Login Handler which takes the response and dispatches data to redux (userdata and json web tokens). I also do have an interval to renew JWTs every X minutes.

However the subscribed state returns undefined and I´m quite unsure why. If I track the redux store there is data written successfully to it. What do I miss here?

```
const App = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const logedInUser = useSelector(state => state.logedInUser.logedInUser)
    const tokens = useSelector(state => state.token.tokens)
    const intervalRef = useRef();

    const refreshToken = useCallback(async () => {
        console.log(tokens.refreshToken) //prints undefined
        console.log(logedInUser.id) //prints undefined
        let response = await restAPI("post", hostAPI +  "/refreshToken", {token: tokens.refreshToken})
        dispatch(setTokens({
            accessToken: response.accessToken,
            refreshToken: response.refreshToken
        }))
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => refreshToken(), 30000)
        intervalRef.current = interval;
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [refreshToken])

    const loginHandler = async (data) => {
        let response = await restAPI("post", hostAPI + "/login", {email: data.email, password: data.password}) //Simple Fetch with Post method returns response as JSON
        if(response.user.id) {
            console.log("RESPONSE",response) //Prints correct Response
            dispatch(setLogedInUser(response.user)) //Dispatch returned Data to redux
            dispatch(setTokens({
                accessToken: response.accessToken,
                refreshToken: response.refreshToken
            }))
        }
    }
```

TokenSlice as example (redux toolkit used):

```
const initialState = {
    tokens: []
}
export const tokenSlice = createSlice({
    name: "token",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setTokens: (state, action) => {
            state.tokens = action.payload
            console.log("Token:", state.tokens) //Prints out correct Tokens afterDispatch
        },
    }
})
```

If I build up a Component with a button in which I Refresh the Token on click everything works as expected. I´m sure that it is just a silly little thing what I´m missing here but since I´m pretty new to Redux I can´t point out what is the issue here is.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I´ve noticed something else. If I change some code and Save it the next "Refresh Token Interval" does print out the correct values. Means somehow "tokens" never updates from the Initial empty state - at least in app component. Like mentoined the redux state itself holds the right values.

Comment: Hey check your code variables properly. you have initialized `tokens` as array and you are taking `state.token.tokens`

Comment: @TusharMistry thanks for your answer! If I initialize tokens as an empty object in initial state it is the same result

Answer (score 0):

I think your method of fetching data from API is wrong. I'm seeing that in your code snippets. You are not using any package like Axios or API request mode. Please see any tutorial on **how to fetch data from API?**
Try to do this work by using :

```
    const Axios = require("axios");
    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Comment: The Fetch is working fine - I´m receiving exactly the results that I want to